# Sketch the region bounded by the graphs of the equations and find the area of that region.

Tags: calculus

y = 1/x^2, y = 4, x = 5.

[image]

Having some trouble bringing this problem to an answer because when I go to solve for the integral boundaries, a and b, I get 1/2 and -1/2 which doesn't correspond with what the graph is telling me. Right now I'm at the integrating stage and I have (sorry don't know how to format this correctly):

integrate from -1/2 to 1/2 (4-1/x^2)dx

Comment: Your graph is telling you that you should be integrating over the interval $[\frac 12, 5]$  So, you solve for the intersection of $y=\frac 1{x^2}$ intersecting $y = 4$  getting 2 solutions.  You need to dismiss one as irrelevant (why?).  Finding the intersection of $y= 4, x = 5$ is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is
$$
\int_{1/2}^5 (4-1/x^2)\,dx,
$$
because this is the only bounded area defined by these conditions and the area between two functions $u(x)$ (upper) and $l(x)$ (lower) on the interwal $(a,b)$ is equal to:
$$
\int_a^b (u(x)-l(x))\,dx.
$$

Comment: True. I don't know why I was finding the solutions. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When integrating with respect to $x$ (as you're doing), your limits must reflect so.  In this case, you want the region between $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $5$, and so the integral you want is
$$A=\int^{5}_{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{x^2} \text{d}x$$
However that gives you the area between the graph $y=1/x^2$ and the $x$-axis.  But that's easily fixed by subtracting the area of the rectangle formed by the lines $y=0,4$ and $x=\frac{1}{2},5$.  The final answer is thus
$$\text{Ans}=9-A$$